# Why is a characteristic of a sample called statistic and not something else?

Tags: terminology, sample

Is there any *hidden* meaning/reason that I'm missing for the word statistic to be used on the above definition? Because as you may know, beginners in Statistics studies can get confused with the term.

Comment: There are two characteristics that make a sample statistic. It is chosen from a **statistical population** which means a set of similar objects for your experiments and another one is  having a **procedure**  for choosing  a sample: http://www.stat.wmich.edu/s216/book/node28.html

Comment: It's not clear what you're seeking here. What kind of answer would suffice? We're presumably discussing Noun meaning 2 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/statistic) -- "A quantity calculated from the data in a sample". There's no big secret to naming things -- people call things what they call them because it seemed like a reasonable thing at the time. The term *statistics* was used in a reasonably modern sense in the later half of the 19th century, and *statistic* as a single piece of numerical information was also used then (if rarely). Its modern sense seems to be an invention of Fisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's just a convention. The etymology of the word itself is interesting, being related to "state", because the earliest uses of the word "statistics" were about nations in particular. But this doesn't have much to do with the modern technical meaning of "statistic", which is "measurable function of the data".